# Popular tabela utilizando duas que não tem ligação

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Pessoal estou com um pequeno problema tenho a seguinte situação:

- tabela `escritorio` onde eu tenho um campo chamado `id` que vou precisar
- tabela `etapas` onde eu tenho os campos `id` que vou precisar;

Eu preciso popular uma tabela chamada `etapasemuso` onde a mesma tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
etapasemuso
emusoid int,
etapasid int,
escritorioid int,
ativo char(1),
etapaok char(1)
```

Para popular essa tabela acima eu preciso buscar dados na tabela `escritorio` e etapas, porém eu não tenho como interligar a mesma visto que não existe chave entre elas. Alguém saberia me dizer como montar uma consulta para popular essa tabela acima?

Comment: Mas se não existe elo entre as duas tabelas como você pretende combinar os dados das duas? Quer fazer um simples produto cartesiano, isto é cada entrada da tabela escritório combinada com todas as entradas existentes na tabela  etapas? Isto faz sentido?

Comment: Exato todas as entradas de escritorio combinado com etapas

Comment: não precisa existir chave para ser fazer um join entre tabelas, agora se elas não um campo em comum vai ser impossível, é como se vc quisesse ligar uma tabela de "pessoas" com uma tabela de "minerais em marte", não é possível relacionar, e não faria sentido. Nesse caso, vai ser um cartesiano como o @anonimo mencionou, ai é só colocar as duas tabelas no `from` e ser feliz (ou não)  ;)

Comment: algo como `select escritorio.id, etapas.id from escritorio, etapas`

Comment: Utilize um CROSS JOIN, seria algo do tipo: INSERT INTO etapasemuso(etapasid, escritorioid) SELECT etapas.id, escritorio.id FROM etapas, escritorio;
mas continuo achando meio sem sentido.

Comment: Tanto o Cross join com o select acima resolveram meu problema obrigado pela ajuda mais uma para coleção esse cross join abraços a todos

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um `CROSS JOIN` que nada mais é do que um `JOIN` sem vínculos entre as tabelas, o que irá "juntar" todos os registros da tabela 1 com todos os registros da tabela 2:

```
INSERT INTO etapasemuso(etapasid, escritorioid)
SELECT e1.id, e2.id
  FROM etapas e1
 CROSS JOIN escritorio e2
```

Comment: Perfeito me ajudou muito não conhecia o cross join deu certo

Comment: @EderLuca não esqueça de aceitar a resposta caso a mesma tenha lhe ajudado